# SonarQube maven compatibility (Unsupported major.minor version 52.0)

Tags: sonarqube, maven-plugin, code-standards, sonar-maven-plugin

I have a multi-module maven project with the following versions of softwares:

```
Maven : 3.2.1
JDK : 1.6
sonar-maven-plugin : 3.4.0

SonarQube server : 6.7.0 (Build 33306)
```

I get the following error on running `clean sonar:sonar` :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project MyProject: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar failed: Unable to load the mojo 'sonar' in the plugin 'org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/SonarQubeMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905
    [ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
```

I believe it has got something to do  with the compatibilty of all the software togather. Can someone help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

It means that you have to use JDK 8 or newer instead of JDK 6.

See more about `maroj.minor` versions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432195/4944847).

Comment: I have a project which can built and deployed using JDK 1.6 only. A version above creates issues with the build.
Now to analyse the project using Sonar (deployed on another server with sonar version 6.7.0) I am getting this issue. I cannot update JDK version or else my project wont build.

Comment: You can build your project with JDK6 and after the build run `sonar:sonar` with JDK8. This is the only option which you have.

Comment: thanks agabrys! I guess I have only this option left. :)

Answer (score 1):

set java 8 and try to build, as below

`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)`

make sure you, it set to java 8

`java -version`
you must see result as below

java version "1.8.0_162"

execute following command to build

`mvn sonar:sonar   -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.login=3554cf2f4ed3edd014b9c52a62a2d3c0a0604315 -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2`